# Create Spring ApplicationContext from in memory XML

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to create an ApplicationContext (or whatever else in Spring you can use to do `getBean("beanName")` ) by passing in an XML file that is in memory?  The only methods I've been able to find involve providing a file or directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give it a try:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;

String xmlDef = "...";
ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlDef.getBytes("UTF-8"))))
```

Comment: This got me to the actual solution, thanks!  `new GenericXmlApplicationContext(new ByteArrayResource(xmlDef.getBytes("UTF-8")))`